# AWS Amplify - Disable Current User Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

[AWS Amplify Authentication module](https://aws.github.io/aws-amplify/media/authentication_guide#working-with-the-api) has some methods for actions like sign in, sign up, forgot password etc. Even one can let the user to update his/her info through like:

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'

// Auth API Sign-in sample
Auth.signIn(username, password)
    .then(user => console.log(user))
    .catch(err => console.log(err))

// Auth API Change info sample
let result = await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
    'email': 'me@anotherdomain.com',
    'family_name': 'Lastname'
})
```

However, I could not see anyway to **disable** (beware, **not to delete**) an account.

So, a user can sign up to a web application, but cannot *deactivate* it using AWS Amplify? If not, are there any other ways for disabling an AWS Cognito User Pool user via Javascript code?

Answer (score 3):

I went through the AWS Documentation for the Cognito User Pools API and found some methods that let a function with admin privileges disable(not delete)  a Cognito User Pool account!

Here is the link to the documentation on the AWS website: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDisableUser.html

There is also a method to reenable the user:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminEnableUser.html

The javascript implementation for this can be found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#adminDisableUser-property

The code would be something like this using the AWS SDK for JS:

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({apiVersion: '2016-04-18'});

var params = {
  UserPoolId: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
  Username: 'STRING_VALUE' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDisableUser(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Good point, or rather a workaround. But still without the admin user privileges, being able to disable *only* own account is not the case here.